# Remove certain tags and the html between them - Jquery

Tags: jquery

If I have a string that contains this.

```
Hi my name is <span class="name">Joe</span>. Just wanted to say <b>Hi</b>.
```

And I want to remove certain tags including what fills it. Example with this string would be the `<span>` tag only.

**I would remove**

`<span class="name">Joe</span>`

**...and the finished output would be**

```
Hi my name is . Just wanted to say <b>Hi</b>.
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Is that string just a js string or part of document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either do this with

```
jQuery('<div>' + yourstring + '</div>').find('span').remove();
```

or

```
jQuery('<div>' + yourstring + '</div>').find('.name').remove();
```

Pick the second one if you only want to remove the element with the class "name".

A working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZWw6d/

Have a look at the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/remove/

Comment: could you give a complete example that uses that string?

Comment: it works if you enclose your string in an element... I'll update the anser

Comment: of course it works if you wrap the text with an element - I've already given that answer

Comment: And finally it got a checkmark :-S After I added my answer and told that this one is incomplete. Great

Answer (score 0):

You have two options with jQuery 1.4 or later:

`jQuery('.name').remove();`

or

`jQuery('.name').detach();`

These are similar except that detach is more suitable if the element is being reinserted into the DOM.

See:

- http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-removal/
- http://api.jquery.com/detach/